# Rider Xamarin error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified

Tags: android, xamarin, rider

Just trying out Rider and came to this problem, if I just build the Xamarin Android project - it builds perfectly fine, however if I try to run it, it fails on deploy step with the following error:

```
▼ Project Not Found
    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
    Switch: Files\JetBrains\Rider

    For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

Not really even sure where to start with this problem

Edit: Forgot to mention - Windows 10

Comment: What is your  `/p:PublishDir` setting?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT bin\Debug\app.publish\

Comment: did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

In our case the Android NDK has been causing the problem. When we removed the path to the NDK (File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Android), the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is most likely located on a path with spaces in it. Normally you should use quotes on the path to make sure it's not understood as multiple arguments but I'm not sure how to do that on Rider.

I'd just move the solution to a location without spaces in the file path.

Comment: The soluton path is - C:\AndroidApp4\AndroidApp4
So I guess that's a no?
Android SDK path is in C:/Android (which I thought was the cause at first)